# Use one font for `\mathcal`, but another font for general math (ConTeXt)

Tags: fonts, context, math-fonts

I want to use (for example) Tex Gyre Heros Math for `\mathcal`, but (for example) Tex Gyre Pagella Math in general for mathematics.
(Why did I want to do that, because Pagella's `\mathcal` seems quite illegible to me.)
I guess the keyword `uppercasescript` (resp. `lowercasescript`) for [definefontfallback](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definefontfallback) is related for my purpose, but `definefontfallback` obviously does not fit the situation.

For concreteness, consider that I use

```
\definefontfeature [default] [default] [onum=yes]
\definefontfamily [MainFace] [rm] [TeX Gyre Pagella]
\definefontfamily [MainFace] [ss] [TeX Gyre Heros]
\definefontfamily [MainFace] [tt] [TeX Gyre Cursor] [features=none]
\definefontfamily [MainFace] [mm] [Tex Gyre Pagella Math]
\setupbodyfont [MainFace, 12pt]
```

But if replace the above line by (merely according to my guess)

```
\definefontfamily [MainFace] [mm] [Tex Gyre Pagella Math]
\definefontfamily [MainFace] [mm] [Tex Gyre Heros Math] [range=uppercasescript]
```

That doesn't work; Tex Heros is used throughout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the `\definefontfamily` command to set the font for your document you can use `\definefallbackfamily` to set replacements for certain characters.

One problem in your original question is that you try to load `TeX Gyre Heros Math` which doesn’t exist and as a result nothing will be replaced.

```
\definefontfamily     [MainFace] [rm] [TeX Gyre Pagella]
\definefallbackfamily [MainFace] [mm] [TeX Gyre DejaVu Math] [force=yes,range=lowercasescript]
\definefontfamily     [MainFace] [mm] [TeX Gyre Pagella Math]

\setupbodyfont [MainFace, 12pt]

\starttext
\m{abc \mathscript abc}
\stoptext
```

Comment: Btw, how do I find what font has been installed within the standard TeX Live, at least a list of TeX Gyre fonts, and math fonts? Like you saw, I Googled the name Heros, but did not know there is no Heros Math.

Comment: @Aminopterin you can use `mtxrun --script fonts --list  --all` to list all fonts on your system. You can even filter the results using `--pattern=`, e.g. `mtxrun --script fonts --list  --pattern='*Gyre* '--all` will give you all TeX Gyre fonts on your system.